# Is there an IMS that can handle interchangeable variants grouped under one SKU?

Tags: inventory

I work for a company that deals in a particular variety of programmable devices. We have roughly 7,000 distinct hardware SKUs, each of which can be programmed with one of several associated software versions depending on the customer's specifications. We're trying to find inventory management software that will account for this type of interchangeable variation. Our customers order based on the software version number, not the hardware SKU, so anyone creating an order (whether a customer or a salesperson) must be able to do so using the software number rather than the SKU. Using a software number as a SKU is also not an option, as we program these parts to the customer's order and not before.

I'm perfectly capable of coding a custom solution for this scenario, and had been doing so, but management now insists on an out-of-the-box solution. This solution must also be able to integrate with Quickbooks Online and with an appropriate e-commerce platform.

So far I've had no luck finding a solution that meets these needs. Every system I've found that handles variants treats them as distinct entities that cannot be freely interchanged with one another (e.g., a shirt that comes in small, medium, and large), which won't work for our use case.

Does anyone know of such a solution, or should I impress on management that this must be custom-coded?

Comment: I am confused, surely the customer has to specify the hardware and software.  You could have them as two distinct products that are selected.  Otherwise "Complex Products" or "Compound Products" feature may work for you.

Comment: The customer does not know the hardware, only the software. Behind the scenes, we match the software to the associated hardware SKU. But there are several possible software numbers that can be applied to any given hardware SKU.

Comment: It still sounds to me like a compound product feature will do the job. So look for that.